# How do I capture lost focus on a Textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a texbox tbx1, when I have the cursor blinking on the textbox, when I click the mouse on some other control I want to display a message, But the issue is I have to use an event of the textbox tbx1 to capture that focus change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Leave` event

```
private void txtbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //your Code
}
```

You can also use,

```
private void txtbox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //your Code
}
```

`Leave()` event first executes keyboard event and then executes mouse event where as `LostFocus()` event first executes mouse event and then executes keyboard event.

Basically When you change the focus by using the keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and so on), the events occurred in the following order

```
1. Enter
2. GotFocus
3. Leave
4. Validating
5. Validated
6. LostFocus
```

When you change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus method, focus events occur in the following order:

```
1. Enter
2. GotFocus
3. LostFocus
4. Leave
5. Validating
6. Validated
```

Comment: obviously the question was about mouse click. The solution only covers events triggered with TAB key. None of these fire on mouse click outside the textbox.

Answer (score 4):

Also there is a [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to do this:

```
private void txtbox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your Code
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use jquery...

```
<input id="txtName" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#txtName").blur(function () {
        alert("I am not in textbox.");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the OP specified windows form